# VBA TypeText Word Wrapping inline with previous line's indentation

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a VBA script in Excel which generates a simple report in MS Word. It loops through a 2d array, and prints each row as a line (with a few transformations and checks).

My problem is: Each line begins with 2 tabs, and whenever a line is too long to fit it will wrap onto the next. This new line begins at the beginning of the page, however, I need to be aligned with the previous line and start with 2 tabs.

Here is the code as is:

```
Sub Macro()

Dim i As Long
Dim szLine As String
szLine = "EXAMPLE STRING DATA, EXAMPLE STRING DATA, EXAMPLE STRING DATA, EXAMPLE STRING DATA"

'Header information
Selection.TypeText Text:="1. PARA 1"
Selection.TypeText Text:=vbCrLf
Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab & "(a) SUB PARA"
Selection.TypeText Text:=vbCrLf

For i = 1 To 5
    'Create String Line to Print
    szLine = "EXAMPLE STRING DATA, EXAMPLE STRING DATA, EXAMPLE STRING DATA, EXAMPLE STRING DATA"
    szLine = vbTab & vbTab & i & "." & vbTab & szLine
    
    'Print
    Selection.TypeText Text:=szLine
    Selection.TypeText Text:=vbCrLf
Next i
End Sub
```

[Here is an image showing an example of the document as is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RGrx.png)

[And here is how I need the document to be formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lwzj.png)

My current solution is to detect whether the current line is above or below a certain threshold number of characters, and if so then I insert a newline char, followed by tabs into the string.

Here is the code for this solution:

```
Public Function FixTabs(sz As String) As String

FixTabs = "NULL"

Dim numTabs As Long
Dim numSplit As Long
Dim sepSplit As String

Dim szReturn As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim hasSplit As Boolean
Dim charLimit As Long

numTabs = 2
numSplit = 3
sepSplit = ","

'Determined by trial and error. Tabs are 5 chars long-ish
charLimit = (numTabs * 5) + 10

'Return the string as is if its not too big
If LenB(sz) < charLimit Then
MsgBox LenB(sz)
    FixTabs = sz
    Exit Function
End If

'Otherwise iterate through, and split the line by the sep char.
hasSplit = False
szReturn = ""
j = 0
For i = 1 To LenB(sz)

    'Build the return string
    szReturn = szReturn & Mid(sz, i, 1)

    If Mid(sz, i, 1) = sepSplit Then
        'Seperator found
        j = j + 1
    Else
        'Check when to insert the new line
        If j >= numSplit And hasSplit = False Then
            hasSplit = True 'Only do this once.
            szReturn = szReturn & vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab 'Add newline and more tabs
        End If
    End If
Next i

FixTabs = szReturn

End Function
```

As you can see, this is less than ideal. It works only 90% of the time as the actual data is less consistent, characters aren't always the same.

My constraints are:

- I must use Times new Roman (no mono spaced fonts)
- I can't use word bullets feature

EDIT:

```
.Paragraphs.LeftIndent = 72
```

Is what I ended up using. Not perfect but it seems exactly what I needed is not possible.

Comment: I don’t know the ms-word object model well enough to tell you how to do it with VBA, but in Word you want to set an explicit indentation level (I think that’s a paragraph attribute).  This might work just like that (and then you would need to undo the indentation setting when you finish these lines) or else you’d need to explicitly set the indentation before every line, or alternatively change the hard line breaks (vbCrLf) to soft line breaks (not sure how).

Comment: And why can't you use bullets? It's word, and bullets would solve your issue. You'd be better off making HTML and having word load that.

Comment: its a pretty hard requirement that the document needs to be formatted this way unfortunately. I'm not able to use anything other than VBA as well. I will try the paragraph settings that might be it.

Comment: Bullets are not at all necessary to address this.

Answer (score 3):

You really need to spend some time learning the basics of how Word works. It is appallingly bad practice to brute-force layouts with tabs and the like.

Learn to use paragraph indents (first line, hanging, left right) instead of tabs and, better still, paragraph Styles - since *everything* to do with paragraph formatting in Word in based on paragraph Styles.

Additionally, you need to learn to use Word templates. With a template, all your boilerplate text, basic formatting and paragraph Styles can all be in place so that all you need to is insert the corresponding content at the relevant locations.

Finally, learn how to use Range objects. Using Selection is inefficient and error-prone.

To give you an idea of what's possible, run the following macro in a new, empty document. This macro would only be needed once to configure a template.

```
Sub ApplyMultiLevelHeadingNumbers()
Dim LT As ListTemplate, i As Long
Set LT = ActiveDocument.ListTemplates.Add(OutlineNumbered:=True)
For i = 1 To 3
  With LT.ListLevels(i)
    .NumberFormat = Choose(i, "%1.", "(%2)", "%3.")
    .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = Choose(i, wdListNumberStyleArabic, wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter, _
      wdListNumberStyleArabic)
    .NumberPosition = 0
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5 + i * 0.5)
    .ResetOnHigher = True
    .StartAt = 1
    .LinkedStyle = "Heading " & i
  End With
  With ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading " & i)
    .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(i * 0.5 - 0.5)
    .ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints(-0.5)
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Bold = False
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

Then run the following macro:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set Rng = .Range(0, 0)
  With Rng
    .Text = "Para 1" & vbCr
    .Paragraphs(1).Range.Style = wdStyleHeading1
    .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
    .Text = "Sub Para" & vbCr
    .Paragraphs(1).Range.Style = wdStyleHeading2
    .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
    .Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa." & vbCr & _
      "Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna." & vbCr & _
      "Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus." & vbCr & _
      "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Aenean nec lorem." & vbCr
    .Style = wdStyleHeading3
    .Start = .Paragraphs(4).Range.End
    .Text = "Sub Para" & vbCr
    .Paragraphs(1).Range.Style = wdStyleHeading2
    .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
    .Text = "In porttitor. Donec laoreet nonummy augue. Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc." & vbCr & _
      "Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy. Fusce aliquet pede non pede. Suspendisse dapibus lorem pellentesque magna. Integer nulla." & vbCr & _
      "Donec blandit feugiat ligula. Donec hendrerit, felis et imperdiet euismod, purus ipsum pretium metus, in lacinia nulla nisl eget sapien." & _
      "Donec ut est in lectus consequat consequat. Etiam eget dui. Aliquam erat volutpat." & vbCr & _
      "Sed at lorem in nunc porta tristique. Proin nec augue. Quisque aliquam tempor magna. " & _
      "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nunc ac magna." & vbCr
    .Style = wdStyleHeading3
    .Start = .Paragraphs(4).Range.End
    .Text = "Para 2" & vbCr
    .Paragraphs(1).Range.Style = wdStyleHeading1
    .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
    .Text = "Sub Para" & vbCr
    .Paragraphs(1).Range.Style = wdStyleHeading2
    .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
    .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
    .Text = "Maecenas odio dolor, vulputate vel, auctor ac, accumsan id, felis. Pellentesque cursus sagittis felis." & vbCr
    .Style = wdStyleHeading3
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

As you will see, the output is formatted as you describe with nary a tab in your data.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not really up to me. The document must absolutely be only tabs and new lines like this.

Comment: Done *properly*, you don't need the tabs - you wouldn't even need the paragraph #s, since every paragraph would be auto-numbered and would contain no more than a simple text stream. Indents have no effect on the *content*. Even with the tabs, you have no guarantee the document will be formatted correctly when viewed on a system using a different printer. That's because Word uses data from the active printer driver to optimise the page layout for that printer.

Comment: @xolol41705  I'd strongly advise you to go back to your boss and/or customer and ask for a modification to the requirements then.  Indentation is the right way to do this, *not* Tabs.   Any solution relying on tabs and counting character widths is not only going to be difficult to implement, it will be extremely fragile as well.  Almost any conceivable change to the document would be in danger of breaking it.  Change the margins, paper size,  paper orientation, font size, bolding, minor edits, national differences in kerning, etc., etc.  Indentation is in Ms-Word to address this exact problem.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yep. That's what I ended up doing. I said it was not possible without paragraph formatting.